# arangosh cannot connect to endpoint when endpoint is 0.0.0.0

Tags: shell, arangodb

I have arangodb running on a centos root server, initially with default endpoint 127.0.0.1:8529. With this initial setup, I can easily connect via arangosh (running on the same server).

In order to access my arangodb as a web service from anywhere, I changed arangod.conf to endpoint 0.0.0.0:8425 and the arangosh.conf endpoint accordingly. From then on, I can access the web interface from anywhere without a problem but arangosh unfortunately refuses to connect on the server itself. The error message simply states "cannot connect".

How can I get the shell working again?

Answer (score 2):

`0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address you could connect to from the ArangoShell. However, in IPv4 this address has some [other implicit meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), and on the server side (arangod) it is used to bind to "any IPv4 address at all". Note that this is on the ArangoDB database side, not the client side.

That means you can use this special address on the server, but not when connecting from the ArangoShell. In the ArangoShell, you will have to specify the server's IP address (as exposed to the clients).